# Why would this be a not found URL using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm having a weird scenario, where PHP's cURL won't be able to resolve a host but instead returns the Header code 400, which is wrong - the website is up, here is the url :

```
http://www.mesearcher.com/persoon/Tim%20Hooper.html
```

and here is my PHP's cURL code.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // return headers
            CURLOPT_NOBODY         => true,     // we don't need content
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_HTTPGET        => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
    , // who am i
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 10,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,


    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,trim(urldecode($url)));
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($ch === FALSE){
        return "Error : <b><u>".curl_error($ch)."</b></u>";
    }
    if($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode < 400 ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return "$httpCode - Additional : ". curl_errno($ch);
    }
```

The website works perfectly fine in browser, i have seen its headers, even blocked page from setting cookies to make sure its not the cookie issue, the `curl_errno` returns `0` as error number which is weird too. Additionaly the websites `http://www.mesearcher.com/` works fine and returns true. But when the query `/persoon/Tim%20Hooper.html` is appended , it mysteriously returns just error code 400.

Where could i be wrong?

Best

Comment: Have you tried this with straight Linux cURL, from the command line?

Comment: No, i am on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inadvertently losing the valid coding for the space in the url.

So you need to put the %20 back in.

Try something like this :

```
$url = trim(urldecode('http://www.mesearcher.com/persoon/Tim%20Hooper.html'));
$url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
```